# How to move a DB2 SQL result table into a physical file?

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I would like to get the result table from a `SELECT` statement, and then move it into a physical file.

I was hoping to use (per [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp)):

```
SELECT column_name(s)
INTO new_table_name [IN externaldatabase]
FROM old_tablename
```

Unfortunately per the IBM Manual (DB2 for i SQL reference)

> The `SELECT INTO` statement produces a result table consisting of at **most one row**, and assigns the values in that row to variables.

So then I thought maybe I could use:

> The `INSERT` statement inserts rows into a table or view
>       There are three forms of this statement:
>   1. The `INSERT` using *fullselect* form is used to insert one or more rows into the table or view using values from other tables or views.

Unfortunately it does not seem to work for me.

```
INSERT INTO <tablename>
FROM ( SELECT (*) FROM <querytableA>
       UNION
       SELECT (*) FROM <querytableB>)
```

I am able to move a result table into a physical file, but to do this I have to declare a cursor and then with a `do … while` write to the physical file, one record at a time. I consider this **ugly and unelegant** and was hoping to be able to use a `SELECT INTO` or a `INSERT INTO` statement.

Please help me “dump” the result table into a physical file with one elegant statement.

OS: IBM i v6.1
Database: DB2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to create the table automatically you can also use the following form:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name 
AS (SELECT * FROM <querytableA> 
    UNION SELECT * FROM <querytableB>) WITH DATA
```

Note that you can create a view over the query to dynamically build the result set on demand.  The view can then be referenced from any HLL as a logical file:

```
CREATE VIEW new_table_name
AS SELECT * FROM <querytableA>
   UNION SELECT * FROM <querytableB>
```

Comment: WITH DATA does not work on our DB2 10.5 only WITH NO DATA !!?? Is it a setting or version issue?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the correct syntax:

```
INSERT INTO <dest_table> 
Select * FROM <querytableA>
UNION
Select * FROM <querytableB>
```

For this to work, `<dest_table>` must already exist and have columns compatible with those in `<querytableA>` and `<querytableB>`.

See "[Inserting rows using a select-statement](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/sqlp/rbafyinsert.htm)" for more info.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do. But I some how got the columns wrong in the table I created. Thanks to a combination of both your and @JamesA's answers I was able to solve the problem.